# Write JSON value to SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, json, uwp

I have JSON like this

```
"id": 823,
"parent_id": 0,
"status": "on-hold",
"order_key": "wc_order_562b39a2050f2",
"currency": "USD",
"version": "2.4.7",
"prices_include_tax": false,
"date_created": "2015-10-24T07:56:18",
"date_modified": "2015-10-24T07:56:18",
"customer_id": 0,
"discount_total": 0.00,
"discount_tax": 0.00,
"shipping_total": 0.00,
"shipping_tax": 0.00,
"cart_tax": 0.00,
"total": 76.98,
"total_tax": 0.00,
```

I parse it like this `

```
 RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("*******", "*******", "*********");
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
        //Get all products
         var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "per_page", "100" }});




        string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();`
```

I need to take for example `"total"` field  and write it to field in database.

For database write I have for example this code `MySqlCommand addCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO demotable (salary,surname) VALUES (1234,'Luk')", connection);
   addCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

But I can have much orders. I need to do this for each order in JSON.

How I can do this?

Comment: Short answer "In a loop". Please parameterize your sql as well to avoid injection attacks. You already have an object collection returned by GetOrders why in the world are you doing the ToFormattedJsonString and THEN trying to put it in the db?

Comment: `ToFormattedJsonString` is to display in console.@PaulSwetz

Comment: Well then the JSON has nothing to do with your problem, just loop the orders collection.

Comment: Thats not valid complete JSON and it doesnt match your `(salary,surname)` example.  If you only need one or two pieces of info, you could use JSON.NET to parse out the values you want in a loop.

Comment: Okay. I use my Json answer and take it there [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to deserialize it. Is it right? @PaulSwetz

Comment: VS can create the classes for you: copy the JSON to the clipboard and then **Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON As Classes**.  Parsing would be simpler if you just want a few bits of data

Comment: Okay , great it works. I have classes.

How I can take for example `email` field for every order (for now there is 28 orders) and write every field in SQL database? @Plutonix

Comment: As I said at the outset, that is not complete and valid json, so I cannot tell you how to work with something I do not know the format of.  I **guess* you would deserialize to a List or Array of those class objects, then loop thru that.

Comment: Okay. This is valid `JSON` [link to JSON](http://pastebin.com/e5RvyScw)

And this is classes in my `.cs ` file [link to classes](http://pastebin.com/MuQRzjYF) @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Plutonix Answer is correct. But I want to show another way of handling this.

[Newtonsoft Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) is a popular Json Parser that can be achieved this. This is a very useful package. install this package from the link.

so if your json string is

```
string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();
```

your code will be

```
List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);
```

now you can loop through items like below.

```
foreach(RootObject root in rootObjectData)
{
    foreach(Class1 c in root.Property1)
    {
        int id = c.id;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I used `RootObject` here from the pastebin URL that you mentioned in your comments.

Comment: Great. Thank's. I have one question.


How I can get data from `id` for example?

I know this is simple question, but I have works with this first time.

Comment: @Eugene Updated Answer to get `id`

Comment: okay, thank's so much. maybe you mean `root.Property1` instead of `ro.Property1`?

Comment: have this `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in `Class1`

Comment: where does it break? Which Line?

Comment: `foreach (Class1 c in root.Property1)` this one

Answer (score 2):

[Your JSON](http://pastebin.com/e5RvyScw) is an array, so if you just want one piece of information from each item, you can get it into a `JArray` to grab the info you want.  This is simpler than deserializing to a class you do not need and are not going to use:

```
string jstr = ... from whereever ...

// get into array
var jobj = JArray.Parse(jstr);

for (int n = 0; n < jobj.Count - 1; n++)
{ 
    // save to a List or update DB 
    Console.WriteLine(jobj[n]["email"]);
}
```

Partial result:

> anastasiya.yenina@gmail.com
>   bakhnovska@gmail.com
>   cosporet@haribu.com

If you need lots of the pieces, you may want to deserialize it to an array or list of T and loop thru that.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize your JSON to an IEnumerable using `Json.net`. use a loop to iterate through your deserialized collection and execute a query for each of them.

Comment: Normally this is correct but in this case he should just loop through the orders collection directly and skip working with the json at all (or just string dumping it for console).